# How to scroll page when PopupMenuButton is opened [flutter]

Tags: flutter, scroll, popupmenu

I am using `PopupMenuButton` of widget but the problem is.. when I open the dialog or click the icon to show PopupMenuItem and then I try to scroll my page.. my page doesn't scroll... so I need to close the dialog first to scroll my page.
Here is the part of the code

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 1,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Text("xxx"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 2,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Text("xxx"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.black)),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

is there a way so that user can keep scrolling when pop up menu dialog is still opened

Comment: Hi uyhaW, have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi @ShudiptoTrafder, I haven't found  yet the solution

Comment: I'm also looking for this, has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: Hi @nosmirck, I haven't found it yet

Comment: I did some research and as of right now, the popupmenu uses a modal barrier that captures all gestures, moreover, there's no way to let the gestures pass through and the only gesture that closes it is a tapUp event that doesn't trigger when dragging (it should be a tap down if we compare to native behavior). You can see my open ticket here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90223 with some ideas on how it should work.